# Whether the series converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

The series is given as
$$\sum_1^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
In the answer the given series diverges. But I don't know how.
Also tell me how $\sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: The series diverges because it is $\ge \sum \frac{1}{n}$, which diverges. For the latter, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))

Answer (score 0):

Since general term $$\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{1}{n}=\dfrac{1+n}{n^2}\sim \dfrac{1}{n}$$ but $$\sum\limits_{n\leqslant N} \dfrac{1}{n}\sim \ln N$$ so initial series diverges